# CSS StyleSheet Not Loading on my website - FF7(Ubuntu)?

Tags: css, linux, wordpress, ubuntu, firefox7

I have updated my word press theme but the css stylesheet doesn't seem to be working on FF7 on Ubuntu OS.
It works perfectly on IE, Chrome, Safari & FF on Windows & Mac; but for some reason, it's not loading on FF in Ubuntu.
It loads well using Chrome on Ubuntu though.

I have no problems with other wordpress themes using this same browser, just my theme seems to be problematic.
I've googled the problem but certain solutions seem to relate to having a general problem with CSS; It seems that only my stylesheet doesn't work.

thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

Install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) on your FF and head to the network tab to see if your .css is found and if it's really not loading. Post any errors here and we'll be able to help you better.

Also, install the [Theme-Check](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-check/) plugin and run it to see if there's any error in the way your css is being called or some conflict.